# how can i renew certbot/letscrypt certificate with same keys?

Tags: android, ssl, certbot, public-key-pinning

I'm noob with SSL.

I have implemented SSL with cerbot/letscrypt [nginx/Ubuntu 14.04]. I had also done public key SSL pinning on the android app. Everything is in production and working fine.

But once the certificate expires i want to renew certificate with the same key to prevent any forceful app update.

Please let me know is there any way i can work around.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I am looking for the same type of solution for Traefik, and as I mention in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62006529/how-to-renew-letsecncrypt-certificates-with-the-same-public-key) I think it's possible for Certbot, at least from reading their `--help`.

So if you run:

```
docker run --rm -it certbot/certbot --help all
```

You will find:

```
--reuse-key           When renewing, use the same private key as the existing certificate. (default: False)
```